# How to remove padding around buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, button

In my Android app, I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="CloseActivity"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@+string/back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the preview and on the phone, it looks like:

[image]

As you can see on the button in the bottom area, there is some padding there.

How can I get rid of that, and let the button fully fill the bottom area?

Comment: DATerre's answer has been correct for two years. Can you mark it as so?

Comment: This question requires editing to have a better title. It has become the first result in Google Search whiile it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

For me the problem turned out to be minHeight and minWidth on some of the Android themes.

On the Button element, add:

```
<Button android:minHeight="0dp" android:minWidth="0dp" ...
```

Or in your button's style:

```
<item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
<item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
```

Comment: Took a while until I realised I'm not dealing with some weird padding behaviour but rather minHeight.

Comment: I don't think this answer actually answers the original question at all. But I'm still glad I came across it because I couldn't figure out why my `Button` was still taking up so much space even after setting its `android:background="@null"`. The fact that the `Button`'s default style is responsible is a very good tip.

Comment: It's important use both android:minHeight="0dp" android:minWidth="0dp", and not only one of them.

Comment: This removes the rounded corner and ripple effect from the button on Android Nougat, any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: This answer solved a problem with a GridLayout containing buttons with autoSize options on the text going berserk as I tried to get more buttons to fit into rows/columns. Simple answer that took me a long time to find...

Answer (score 214):

My solution was set to 0 the insetTop and insetBottom properties.

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/view_video"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 54):

That's not padding, it's the shadow around the button in its background drawable. Create your own background and it will disappear.

Comment: I did. didn't disappear.

Comment: How can its size be measured?

Comment: This is it, @Behr, changing the background to the button's color

Comment: I just realized my background image has transparent padding

Answer (score 41):

for MaterialButton, add below properties, it will work perfectly

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 27):

A workaround may be to try to use `-ve` values for margins like following:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="CloseActivity"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
    android:text="@string/back" />
```

It will make that space vanish. I mean you can choose the appropriate `dip` value, which makes it go away. It worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: I would be careful using this solution. What it does is just hidding button background (border + shadows) using negative margins. What is styling changes and border+shadow takes more then 5dp? I would rather use Delyan/Casey Murray solution to be on the safe side.

Comment: Also, negative margins are not officially supported in Android so I too would avoid this

Answer (score 25):

To remove the Top and Bottom padding

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"//to effect the following parameters, this must be added!
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"/>
```

To remove the Left and Right padding

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"//to effect the following parameters, this must be added!
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 16):

For removing padding around toggle button we need set minWidth and minHeight 0dp.`android:minWidth="0dp" android:minHeight="0dp"`

```
  <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_row_notifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        />
```

set your drawable file to button attribute like: `android:button="@drawable/toggle_selector"`

Below is my `toggle_selecter.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/notifications_toggle_on" 
                  android:state_checked="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/notifications_toggle_off" 
                  android:state_checked="false"/>
     </selector>
```

Answer (score 11):

Add these properties:

```
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `android:padding="0dp"` was also needed (together with `paddingStart`, `paddingEnd` to remove top and bottom paddings and keep left and right).

Answer (score 8):

I am new to android but I had a similar situation. I did what @Delyan suggested and also used android:background="@null" in the xml layout file.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and it seems that it is because of the **background color** of the button. Try changing the background color to another color eg:

```
android:background="@color/colorActive"
```

and see if it works. You can then *define a style* if you want for the button to use.

Comment: This removes the highlighting/animation capability of the button.

Answer (score 6):

In the button's XML set `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Answer (score 5):

It's not a padding but or the shadow of the background drawable or a problem with the `minHeight` and `minWidth`.

If you still want the nice ripple affect, you can make your own button style using the `?attr/selectableItemBackground`:

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.MyCustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to the button:

```
<Button 
    style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.MyCustomButton"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Borderless** style in **AppCompatButton** like below. and use **android:background** with it.

> **style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"**

Button code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button_visa_next"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be padding, margin, or minheight/width.
Setting `android:background="@null"` the button loses its touch animation, but it turns out that setting the background to anything at all fixes that border.

---

I am currently working with:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 2):

A standard button is not supposed to be used at *full width* which is why you experience this.

### Background

If you have a look at the [*Material Design - Button Style*](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-style) you will see that a button has a 48dp height click area, but will be displayed as 36dp of height for...some reason.

This is the background outline you see, which will not cover the whole area of the button itself.
It has rounded corners and some padding and is supposed to be clickable by itself, wrap its content, and not span the whole width at the bottom of your screen.

### Solution

As mentioned above, what you want is a different *background*. Not a standard button, but a background for a selectable item with this nice ripple effect.

For this use case there is the `?selectableItemBackground` theme attribute which you can use for your backgrounds (especially in lists).
It will add a platform standard ripple (or some color state list on < 21) and will use your current theme colors.

For your usecase you might just use the following:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
                   <!--  /\ that's all -->
```

*There is also no need to add layout weights if your view is the only one and spans the whole screen*

If you have some different idea on what your background should look like you have to create a custom drawable yourself, and manage color and state there.

> This answer copied from [**Question:** How to properly remove padding (or margin?) around buttons in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298421/3257579)

Answer (score 2):

For `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>`

```
           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                .
                .
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp" 
               >

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your button a custom background:   @drawable/material_btn_blue

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging around multiple answers I finally found a solution that doesn't use a different element, manipulate `minHeight` or `minWidth`, or even wrapping `Button` around a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<Button
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@color/whatever" />
```

The main takeaway here is the setting of the foreground instead of background as many of the answers stipulate. Changing the background itself to `selectableItemBackground` will just overwrite any changes you made to the button's color/background, if any.

Changing the foreground gives you the best of both worlds: get rid of the "invisible" padding and retain your button's design.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `AppCompatButton` paddings programmatically:

```
button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
button.minHeight = 0
button.minimumHeight = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use (now material) `Button` with style, add there parameters:

```
<style name="SomeButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <!-- Margins between buttons -->
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
    <!-- Remove extra paddings -->
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
</style>

<Button
    style="@style/SomeButton"
    ...
```

In case you set a drawable as a background and want to add some margins, don't use upper code. You should add *top and bottom margins* to the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Top and bottom margins -->
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <!-- Below follows your drawable -->
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="false">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#f0f0f0" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_enabled="true">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffff80" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/some_drawable"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it with `layout_width(height)` parameters.

E.g. I have deleted top and bottom space with `android:layout_height="18dp"` code.