# how to remove space between views in android studio

Tags: android, view, space, android-layout-weight

i want to remove the space between `TextView` and `Button`
i tried to many options but no one worked for now .
thanks in advance and any help will be appreciated .
[the xml code and preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBLYh.png)

this is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="33sp"
    android:text="hello"
    android:background="#cc3"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    android:layout_weight = "3"/>
<Button
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_height = "0dp"
    android:text="Click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try some of the things discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960599/how-to-remove-padding-around-buttons-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a background color to the button and change the text color accordingly. That way the space will be removed.

```
<Button
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"/>
```

Any custom color will do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin.

`android:margin=-2dp`

EDIT: If you want to avoid negative margins, you must create your own (button) view because the standard button view comes with that margin, so you can't remove it

Comment: first, thanks for the answer @Aenadon 
second . i read that we should avoid negative  values .
and it didn`t work .

Comment: Okay, please read my updated answer

Comment: Ohh, you mean to make trick in color so that the space won't be view ? 

Comment: No, I mean that you use something that fills up the whole space, for example, just take TextView, you won't have the button animation but it will fill up the space

Comment: hey, if my answer helped you, please mark my answer as correct... and if not, please tell me what went wrong

Comment: its work and i am sorry for late in marking your answer .
thanks alot

Comment: Update: use android:layout_margin= -2dp

Answer (score 0):

You could always just swap the Button for another TextView and add an OnClickListener to it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:text="hello"
        android:background="#cc3"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        android:layout_weight = "3"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_button"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="Click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Activity:

```
TextView button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do some stuff here
        }
    });
```